# Update SQLite database with Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking for suggestions, tips or anything in between. I'm building an app about movie releases and the user can favorite the movies he's looking the most forward too. Now movie releases data is stored in Firebase and it's updated from a script via Python once a week, and some movies the user can favorite don't have an official release date as of the time he Favorited it. But then when the script got ran; new fresh up to date data is put in my firebase database, this movie has now got an official release date and I was wondering how can I update this release date which is stored in his local database and how can I notify him with a push notification that this data has been changed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firsty, you should mark "movieItem" with the same id in your local database and Firebase as well.
Secondly, I would suggest to make a method filtering all movie records without release dates from your local database.
Next, it should be easy to check if firebase equivalents have "releaseDate" for returned Id, and update this value to SQLite.
If so, get all updated movies names, and push them through FCM. It will require making a proper JSON file, obtaining FCM key and preparing a service for picking up push notification from FCM server.

Firebase Cloud Messaging -> [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/](http://FCM)

The other method is to enable offline firebase capabilities for movies marked as favourite instead of using SQLite. Link below ;)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thank you! From what I understand, I'd need to add a listener that listen to releases on the FavoriteFragment to update the user's local sqlite db?

Comment: I doesn't matter where will you put your listener, it surely depends on your implementation so you know the best if FavoriteFragmen is Ok ;) Yes you'll need to retrive releases from firebase using listener and compare records with those in your SQLite database. Maybe it would be helpful if you could save lastModifiedDate field in your firebase and SQLite record. Then comparing two dates would solve the problem what exact movies should be updated with fresh stuff. Hope I was clear enough ;)